# How to re-render a component (Vue) with its data (and state) intact?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Here's how my code is structured: parent component shuffles through child components via v-if directives, one of the child components is using a state to define its data. Everything works except when I switch between the child components. When I get back, no data can be shown because the state has become null.

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
   <Welcome v-if="view==0" />
   <Courses v-if="view==1" /> //the component that I'm working on
   <Platforms v-if="view==2" />
  </div>
</template>
```

Courses component:

```
<template>
  <div>Content</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Courses',
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'courses'
    ])
  },
  data () {
    return {
      courseList: [],
      len: Number,
    }
  },
  created () {
    console.log("state.courses:")
    console.log(this.courses)
    this.courseList = this.courses
    this.len = this.courses.length
  },
}
</script>
```

Let say the default value for "view" is 1, when I load the page, the "Courses" component will be shown (complete with the data). If I click a button to change the value of "view" to 0, the "Welcome" component is shown. However, when I tried to go back to the "Courses" component, the courses component is rendered but is missing all the data.

Upon inspection (via console logging), I found that when the "Courses" component was initially rendered, the state was mapped correctly and I could use it, but if I changed the "view" to another value to render another component and then changed it back to the original value, the "Courses" component still renders but the state became undefined or null.

EDIT: Clarification.

Comment: I am not able to get your issue here properly. Could you please elaborate it more.

Comment: `this.courseList = this.courses` seems redundant and this also looks like a good candidate for [dynamic components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

Comment: pls avoid this, 3 elements inside an `<template>`. wrap all 3 components in an `<div>`

Comment: sorry, i changed the question to be clearer

Answer (score 0):

Set `courseList` to a component name and use `<component>`
and set some enum

eg.

```
<template>
   <component :is="this.viewState" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    // your stuff
    data() {
      return {
         viewState: 'Welcome',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getComponent(stateNum) {
          const States = { '1': 'Welcome', '2': 'Courses', '3': 'Platforms' }
          Object.freeze(States)
          return States[stateNum]
      }
    },
    created() {
       // do your stuff here 
       const view = someTask() // someTask because I don't get it from where you're getting data
       this.viewState = this.getComponent(view)
    }
}
</script>
```

I don't actually understood correctly but here I gave some idea for approaching your problem.